# Load postfix emails in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, postfix-mta, dovecot

I have **postfix** and **dovecot** in my ubuntu server.
Is there any way to load my emails in Laravel application? I know that my incoming emails store in normal files in a directory ( for example `/var/mail` ) so i need an custom parser to do that ?

1. Is there any way or library to load mails in Laravel ?
2. Is there any way to save emails in DB instead of normal files ? so i can load them easily

**Note** : I just need load and show them, not *send / forward / etc*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not ready out of the box on Laravel (or packages to it) that reads and parse postfix emails, at last I didn't found it.

But there's a great mail parser called [`php-mime-mail-parser`](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser) that you can use to parse the raw email from `/var/mail` directory.

You will need to schedule a job to read this emails at every X minutes, store on a table, then remove them from `/var/mail`.

It isn't so complicated to develop, actually looks simpler then receive emails from Mailgun api for example.

Sorry about the answer don't contain any code, this is really something that you will need to develop.